# How can I set parameter in JSON request header?

Tags: json, rest

I would like to set the userId and Password in JSON request header and remaining parameters in JSON request body. Can any give an example how can i set the userId/password in JSON request header and others parameter in JSON request Body.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: u can use poster for calling that and setting parameters..

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery:

```
<script>
//submit request
$.post('url',{userId: userIdvalue, Password: password value,...},function(response){
// do something when request processed successfully
});
//if you submit a form
$.post('url',{$("#formId".serialize())},function(response){
// do something when request processed successfully
});
</script>
```